keycloak TLS - unexpected eof while reading
I'm trying to build Keycloak in a lab as simply as possible. I have configured AD, successfully connected Keycloak to it, added a client, and now have configured OpenShift to point to Keycloak.
However, Keycloak's TLS seems to be failing.
In the OpenShift logs I see:
I0717 14:17:26.567736       1 status_controller.go:218] clusteroperator/authentication diff {"status":{"conditions":[{"lastTransitionTime":"2024-07-16T12:39:02Z","message":"OAuthServerConfigObservatio
nDegraded: failed to apply IDP keycloak config: read tcp 10.128.0.11:53928-\u003e10.10.25.199:443: read: connection reset by peer","reason":"OAuthServerConfigObservation_Error","status":"True","type":
"Degraded"},{"lastTransitionTime":"2024-07-03T18:23:47Z","message":"AuthenticatorCertKeyProgressing: All is well","reason":"AsExpected","status":"False","type":"Progressing"},{"lastTransitionTime":"20
24-07-12T05:00:25Z","message":"All is well","reason":"AsExpected","status":"True","type":"Available"},{"lastTransitionTime":"2024-07-03T14:41:18Z","message":"All is well","reason":"AsExpected","status
":"True","type":"Upgradeable"},{"lastTransitionTime":"2024-07-03T14:41:17Z","reason":"NoData","status":"Unknown","type":"EvaluationConditionsDetected"}]}}
I0717 14:17:26.573122       1 event.go:364] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Deployment", Namespace:"openshift-authentication-operator", Name:"authentication-operator", UID:"75b35dd4-fa31-4786-be9c-599b
ec999700", APIVersion:"apps/v1", ResourceVersion:"", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'OperatorStatusChanged' Status for clusteroperator/authentication changed: Degraded message changed from "OA
uthServerConfigObservationDegraded: failed to apply IDP keycloak config: EOF" to "OAuthServerConfigObservationDegraded: failed to apply IDP keycloak config: read tcp 10.128.0.11:53928->10.10.25.199:44
3: read: connection reset by peer"

that made me go check Keycloak manually where I noticed curl fails.
[root@r7525-milan ~]# curl -v https://10.10.25.199:443/auth
*   Trying 10.10.25.199:443...
* Connected to 10.10.25.199 (10.10.25.199) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, decode error (562):
* error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
[root@r7525-milan ~]# curl -v https://127.0.0.1:443/auth
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, decode error (562):
* error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading

I ran keycloak with:
docker run -d --name keycloak \
--network keycloak-network \
--user root \
-v /opt/keycloak/data:/opt/keycloak/data \
-e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin \
-e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin \
-e KC_DB=postgres \
-e KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak \
-e KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak \
-e KC_DB_PASSWORD=password \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 443:8443 \
quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.1 start-dev

I have turned off firewalld (I'm on Rocky 9). I noticed that even when I ran:
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=443/tcp --zone=public && firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --reload

port 443 was still coming back as filtered. Turning off firewalld resolved the issue, but now I'm seeing the EOF problem.
I'm beginning to suspect firewalld is doing something wrong with docker because I also tested with 8443 and firewalld is also filtering that.
[root@r7525-milan ~]# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8443/tcp --zone=public && firewall-cmd --reload
success
success
[root@r7525-milan ~]# nmap -p 8443 127.0.0.1
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-07-17 10:30 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00012s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
8443/tcp open  https-alt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.07 seconds
[root@r7525-milan ~]# nmap -p 8443 10.10.25.199
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-07-17 10:31 EDT
Nmap scan report for 10.10.25.199
Host is up.

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
8443/tcp filtered https-alt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.06 seconds

